# VS2012 Winform designer error

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I keep getting the error "Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute".

While in design mode for a winform. Project runs fine, just design time which has an issue.

This goes away after opening and closing the project X times (between 1 and 10+ so far), but always comes back at random times (even when no changes have been made to the project or any of its dependencies).

> > System.ThrowHelper.ThrowInvalidOperationException(ExceptionResource resource)
> >     at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.Enumerator.MoveNextRare()
> >     at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.Enumerator.MoveNext()
> >     at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.VSTypeResolutionService.AssemblySpecFound(List`1 assemblies, String assemblyFullName)
> >     at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.VSTypeResolutionService.AddDependencies(Assembly a, String fileName)
> >     at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.VSTypeResolutionService.AssemblyEntry.get_Assembly()
> >     at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.VSTypeResolutionService.AssemblySpecFound(List`1 assemblies, String assemblyFullName)
> >     at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.VSTypeResolutionService.AddProjectDependencies(Project project)
> >     at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.VSTypeResolutionService.AssemblyEntry.get_Assembly()
> >     at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.VSTypeResolutionService.AssemblyEntry.Search(String fullName, String typeName, Boolean ignoreTypeCase, Boolean allowPrivate, Assembly& assembly, String description)
> >     at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.VSTypeResolutionService.AssemblyEntry.Search(String fullName, String typeName, Boolean ignoreTypeCase, Assembly& assembly, String description)
> >     at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.VSTypeResolutionService.SearchProjectEntries(AssemblyName assemblyName, String typeName, Boolean ignoreTypeCase, Assembly& assembly)
> >     at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.VSTypeResolutionService.SearchEntries(AssemblyName assemblyName, String typeName, Boolean ignoreCase, Assembly& assembly, ReferenceType refType)
> >     at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.VSTypeResolutionService.SearchEntries(AssemblyName assemblyName, String typeName, Boolean ignoreTypeCase, Assembly& assembly)
> >     at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.VSTypeResolutionService.System.ComponentModel.Design.ITypeResolutionService.GetAssembly(AssemblyName name, Boolean throwOnError)
> >     at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.VSTypeResolutionService.System.ComponentModel.Design.ITypeResolutionService.GetAssembly(AssemblyName name)
> >     at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.VSDynamicTypeService.OnAssemblyResolve(Object sender, ResolveEventArgs e)
> >     at System.AppDomain.OnAssemblyResolveEvent(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String assemblyFullName)
> >     at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.GetType(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, ObjectHandleOnStack type)
> >     at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.GetType(String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase)
> >     at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.VSTypeResolutionService.AssemblyEntry.Search(String fullName, String typeName, Boolean ignoreTypeCase, Boolean allowPrivate, Assembly& assembly, String description)
> >     at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.VSTypeResolutionService.AssemblyEntry.Search(String fullName, String typeName, Boolean ignoreTypeCase, Assembly& assembly, String description)
> >     at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.VSTypeResolutionService.SearchProjectEntries(AssemblyName assemblyName, String typeName, Boolean ignoreTypeCase, Assembly& assembly)
> >     at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.VSTypeResolutionService.SearchEntries(AssemblyName assemblyName, String typeName, Boolean ignoreCase, Assembly& assembly, ReferenceType refType)
> >     at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.VSTypeResolutionService.GetType(String typeName, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, ReferenceType refType)
> >     at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.Serialization.CodeDom.AggregateTypeResolutionService.GetType(String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase)
> >     at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.Serialization.CodeDom.AggregateTypeResolutionService.GetType(String name)
> >     at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.DesignerSerializationManager.GetRuntimeType(String typeName)
> >     at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.DesignerSerializationManager.GetType(String typeName)
> >     at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.DesignerSerializationManager.System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.IDesignerSerializationManager.GetType(String typeName)
> >     at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.CodeDomSerializerBase.GetType(IDesignerSerializationManager manager, String name, Dictionary`2 names)
> >     at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.CodeDomSerializerBase.FillStatementTable(IDesignerSerializationManager manager, IDictionary table, Dictionary`2 names, CodeStatementCollection statements, String className)
> >     at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.TypeCodeDomSerializer.Deserialize(IDesignerSerializationManager manager, CodeTypeDeclaration declaration)
> >     at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.CodeDomDesignerLoader.PerformLoad(IDesignerSerializationManager manager)
> >     at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.Serialization.CodeDom.VSCodeDomDesignerLoader.PerformLoad(IDesignerSerializationManager serializationManager)
> >     at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.Serialization.CodeDom.VSCodeDomDesignerLoader.DeferredLoadHandler.Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextManager.Interop.IVsTextBufferDataEvents.OnLoadCompleted(Int32 fReload)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this was a bug that was fixed in [Visual Studio 2012 Update 4](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2872520):

> Windows Forms
>
> - You may receive the following error message in Windows Forms Designer:
> - Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute

Go to [Download Visual Studio 2012 Update 4](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=39305) to get the update.

Comment: Thank you, thought I had the latest patches.